# Azure Webb App Custom Domains gives error TemplateBladeVirtualPart WEBSITESEXTENSION

Tags: azure, dns

In Azure Portal I'll go to my webb app and try to access the custom domains under settings and it gives me this error:

```
TemplateBladeVirtualPart
WEBSITESEXTENSION
```

[image: Error image]